# Xamarin messaging center subscribing multiple times

Tags: c#, xamarin, messagingcenter

I'm dealing with a page that needs to send information to another and I'm doing this through messaging center but I noticed that messages are being sent once and received 2,4,6 times... depending on how many times I opened the subscriber page. The strange is that I had added some code to avoid subscribing more than once. See the relevant part of my code:

Sender:

```
if (result.status == "ok")
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<ChatCompartilhar, PassaParametro>(this, "PopUpData", new PassaParametro(){ Tipo = 3, Valor = result.msg, Extra = dataFinal });
    await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
}
```

Subscriber:

```
Page()
{
  MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<ChatCompartilhar, PassaParametro>(this, "PopUpData");
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ChatCompartilhar, PassaParametro>(this, "PopUpData", async (sender, arg) =>
  {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        switch (arg.Tipo)
        {
          case 2: tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ShareMap(arg))); break;
          case 3: tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ShareEvent(arg))); break;
          case 6: tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ShareImage(arg))); break;
        }
   });
}

~Page()
{
  MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<ChatCompartilhar, PassaParametro>(this, "PopUpData");
}
```

I put line break on sender line and could see it's executed only once but on subscriber, line breaks shows multiple executions. What can I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving current reference, you can try passing the Key name.

```
Page()
{
  MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<ChatCompartilhar, PassaParametro>("SomeKey", "PopUpData");
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ChatCompartilhar, PassaParametro>("SomeKey", "PopUpData", async (sender, arg) =>
  {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        switch (arg.Tipo)
        {
          case 2: tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ShareMap(arg))); break;
          case 3: tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ShareEvent(arg))); break;
          case 6: tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ShareImage(arg))); break;
        }
   });
}

~Page()
{
  MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<ChatCompartilhar, PassaParametro>("SomeKey", "PopUpData");
}
```

Comment: Hey brother, it seemed to work fine. Can you explain me what is the logic of this approach? What is the problem when passing the reference?

Comment: I asked that to you because putting this is what xamarin recommends in this page https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.messagingcenter.unsubscribe?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: When you use `this` it will take the current reference, so there are chances that when you try to subscribe again that reference might have changed. So to avoid this, it's better to use the key.